# Album cover as notification

Tags: android

I am trying to display an album cover as a notification while the song as playing. I want a play icon in the status bar and the album cover to show up when the bar is pulled down. Right now it is a play icon for both of them.

Similar to how the ICS text messaging notification works, it shows the message icon and then when it pulls down it's the picture of the person texting you.

How can I have these images be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom view for a notification, which can contain ImageView's if you wish.
The developer docs have a great example.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView

Here's a snippet from the docs that creates the RemoveViews and sets it as the notifications contentView.

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_layout);
contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.notification_image);
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Custom notification");
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "This is a custom layout");
notification.contentView = contentView;
```

For your album art image you probably don't have a resource, but instead will have a Bitmap or Drawable. So try setImageViewBitmap on the RemoteViews.